# Adjective(ADJ) vs Addjective Phrase(ADJP) in phrase structure trees

Tags: grammar

In phrase structure trees, single adjectives are sometimes written as ADJ, and sometimes as ADJ and ADJP. What is the difference? I've notice the same also applies to adverbs. When is an adjective both ADJ and ADJP? I don't get it.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what adjectives you've seen described in these way?

Comment: TrevorD For example, in the sentence "Pretty girls whisper softly." the adjective pretty is written first as ADJ, then AP(adjective phrase), and then joined by node to form the noun phrase(NP) "pretty girls." Why does it become a adjective phrase, not simply joined to girls as ADJ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're describing.  Might this question be more suitable on English Language Learners http://ell.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: For analysis purposes, for example in a tree diagram, an adjective with or without any dependents such as modifiers is labelled an AdjP. But often when simply contrasting parts of speech, it's just called an adjective (or Adj). The same applies to the other categories: NP = noun phrase; AdvP = adverb phrase; PP = preposition phrase; DP = determinative phrase.

Answer (score 1):

You have run into a little syntactical jargon.  Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey Pullum (*A Student's Guide of English Grammar*) explain:

> Traditional grammars and dictionaries define a **phrase** as containing
>   more than one word. But it' actually more convenient to drop this
>   requirement, and generalize the category 'noun phrase' so that it
>   covers *things*, *Kim*, and *people* ... as well as *all things* and
>   *some people*.... So we prefer to say that a noun phrase (henceforth NP) normally consists of a noun with or without various dependents.
>   (In other words, the head is accompanied zero or more dependents.)

Thus as it is with noun phrases (NP), so it is with adjective phrases (ADJP).

Adjectives (like *difficult*) are words that express the properties of nouns.  In a sentence, *adjectives* may take modifiers (***very*** difficult) and **complements** (*difficult **to say***), and an adjective with its modifiers and complements is called an *adjective phrase*.  It's possible for a sentence to contain an unadorned adjective, i.e., with no modifiers and no complements, and H&P "prefer" to call that unadorned use a phrase anyway.

Comment: deadrat I am almost there. Don't give up on me just yet. I assume that the same goes for adverbs, correct?  Why then in my textbook, is the adverb "softly" written just as an ADV in the phrase structure tree, not ADV and then node ADVP node VP?

Comment: @SimonG H&P don't have trees in their student edition, But Aarts, who agrees about the definition of phrases, does (in *Oxford Modern English Gammar*) and some of his trees shows a node ADVP with only a single subordinate node ADV.  What's your textbook?

Comment: deadrat Sorry I have been away from the computer for a bit. My book is Fromkin, Rodman, Hyams "An Introduction to Language" in which "softly" from the phrase mentioned above is attached directly to the VP without the second ADVP node? "Pretty" as I mentioned has the ADJP node. I don't understand the difference.

Comment: deadrat To continue on the same vein (vain?), in the sentence "I utterly despised the stupid test." should utterly be ADV - ADVP and then connected to the VP "despised the stupid test" or should it be connected simply as ADV - VP? Likewise, should stupid be written as just ADJ or ADJ - ADJP before being attached to NP "the stupid test"?

Comment: @SimonG It's *vein*, as in what you shouldn't open when thinking about this.  It's just a matter of convenience.  If you allow a lone ADJ to be an ADJP, then you can say uniformly that adjective phrases modify nouns.  Otherwise, every time you want to say what modifies nouns you have to say "adjective or adjective phrase". That convenience is somewhat offset by your having to show two nodes for a lone adjective (ADJ-ADJP) instead of one.  (On the other hand, your parse trees are also uniform.)

Comment: deadrat Again you are the KING rat. I understand. Much gratitude.

Comment: deadrat just one more question. Am I right in assuming that in my example phrase, "I utterly despised the stupid test." that the adjective "stupid" would not be written as a ADJP because of the determiner "the", which indicates that no ADJP is possible, while the word "utterly" should be written as a ADVP because there can be one?

Comment: PS. Damn Chomsky!

Comment: @SimonG Consider the noun phrase *all the ridiculously stupid tests*.  Here the NP contains a head (*tests*) that governs a determinative phrase (*all the*), an adjective phrase (*ridiculously stupid*).  Take out the words *all* and *ridiculously*, and you have the same basic structure. It's just that the determinative phase consists of a single determiner (*the*) and the ADJP consists of a single adjective (*stupid*).